# MySQL fulltextsearch: no results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

i use this query for a fulltextsearch in my table:

```
SELECT Titel FROM cmsa WHERE MATCH(Titel) AGAINST ('+"Ort" +"Berlin"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but the result is empty.

If i use

```
SELECT Titel FROM cmsa WHERE Titel LIKE '%Berlin%'
```

the result would be (without quotes):

```
"Ort - Berlin"
```

Why the fulltextsearch didnt find this result. The word "Ort" and the word "Berlin" are both in the field Titel of the entry.

Other fulltext searches works great.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because MySQL has a server parameter - [The minimum length of the word to be included in a FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len). Default value for this parameter is 4 so your first word `Ort` is not included in this index. You should change this system parameter, restart server and then rebuild all FULLTEXT indexes.

```
REPAIR TABLE cmsa QUICK;
```

- [Change the full text index minimum word length with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-full-text-index-word-length/)

Answer (score 2):

Try without double quotes and make sure Mysql engine is `MYISAM`

```
SELECT 
         Titel 
FROM 
         cmsa 
WHERE 
         MATCH(Titel) AGAINST ('+Ort +Berlin' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Some explanation

**Boolean Mode Searches**

```
SELECT headline, story FROM news
WHERE MATCH (headline,story)
AGAINST ('+Hurricane -Katrina' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The above statement would match news stories about hurricanes but not those that mention hurricane katrina.

**Query Expansion**

The Blind Query Expansion (or automatic relevance feedback) feature can be used to expand the results of the search. This often includes much more noise, and makes for a very fuzzy search.

In most cases you would use this operation if the users query returned just a few results, you try it again WITH QUERY EXPANSION and it will add words that are commonly found with the words in the query.

```
SELECT headline, story FROM news
WHERE MATCH (headline,story)
AGAINST ('Katrina' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

The above query might return all news stories about hurricanes, not just ones containing Katrina.

A couple points about Full-Text searching in MySQL:

- Searches are not case sensitive
- Short words are ignored, the default minimum length is 4 characters. You can change the min and max word length with the variables ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len
- Words called stopwords are ignored, you can specify your own stopwords, but default words include the, have, some - see default
  stopwords list.
- You can disable stopwords by setting the variable ft_stopword_file to an empty string.
- Full Text searching is only supported by the MyISAM storage engine.
- If a word is present in more than 50% of the rows it will have a weight of zero. This has advantages on large datasets, but can make
  testing difficult on small ones.

Comment: thanks for your help this expression works for the case. But how do i search for +Ort +"Berlin Kreutzberg" without double quotes?

Answer (score -1):

Your query was working perfectly for me. Please check your table is MYISAM or not because full text search working in only myisam engine.

Comment: The full text search works in other cases in the same table too. Its a MyISAM table with a fulltext index on Titel.